TeXworks ignore syntax-patterns.txt
I would like to customize syntax colouring by editing
~/.TeXworks/configuration/syntax-patterns.txt
but the file is ignored by TeXworks,
restart doesn't help.
version: TeXworks 0.6.6 ("Debian") [r.24442ac0, 11.03.2021 11:03]

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered to update your system?

I have replaced it by the  PPA version 0.6.9, it doesn't help.
